# Which users are on the specific page

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm working on a project where people can be on the same page, modifying the same Mongo document to work together (Google Docs like).

I'm looking a way to get the list of current users on a page.

**eg:**

> I'm on the Post 1. Three others people join me on the edition. I would
>   be able to display:
>
> "You are 4 on this page (You, Toto, Mickael, Julien)"

I guess the naive approch would be to log on a Mongo Doc when users go/leave the route and reactively refresh the UI.

Do you know any others solutions to achieve that? Mine sound a bit "hacky" to me...

Comment: You might want to look at these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643114/how-can-i-display-a-list-of-all-logged-in-users-with-meteor-js

Comment: That actually not dumb to use the in memory minimongo. I will try to implement that, not sure it's useful to add a package dependency for that, it's look pretty simple when you look at the code! ty